# Understanding "dimension of row space" of a matrix using an example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Qn: If the null space of a 7x5 matrix A is 4-dimensional, what is the ***dimension of the row space*** A?

Ans: dimension of row A = 1

I feel like my confusion comes from understanding what the question want when they say dimension, [got validated by this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170009/very-confused-of-dimension-of-a-matrix). Please can you correct/point out any of my knowledge gap?

I'd like to verify the following:

1. My intuitive definition of "dimension of row space" is n.o of rows in A. Am I correct here? ([Wikipedia seem to confirm that row space is n.o of rows in A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces)).
2. Confusingly, also according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#:%7E:text=The%20dimension%20of%20the%20row,equivalently%20the%20number%20of%20pivots.), "dimension of row space" = "rank" = "[n.o of linearly independent columns of A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))". I'm assuming this is for square matrix only and does not apply here?...
3. Given the answer being 1 and considering the above, I try and work backwards, set the following with an example of how I can achieve a single row, is this correct?
4. Feels like a roundabout way to address this question. Is there a more efficient way to tackle this question?

$A\vec{v}=\vec{0}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b&c&d\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ v_4\\ v_5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$v_1+av_2+bv_3+cv_4+dv_5 = 0 \rightarrow v_1 = -av_2-bv_3-cv_4-dv_5$

$Nullspace (\vec{v}) = v_2\begin{pmatrix}-a\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+v_3\begin{pmatrix}-b\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+v4\begin{pmatrix}-c\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\\ \:0\end{pmatrix}+v_5\begin{pmatrix}-d\\ 0\\ \:0\\ \:0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ , such that $v_2, v_3,v_4,v_5$ are $\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are familiar with the concept of *[elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)*. With that in mind

> 1. My intuitive definition of "dimension of row space" is n.o of rows in A. Am I correct here?

No, the dimension of $A$'s row space (also that of its column space) is the number of pivots you have after elimination, i.e., the rank. This can certainly be smaller than $m$.

> 2. Confusingly, also according to wikipedia, "dimension of row space" = "rank" = "n.o of linearly independent columns of A". I'm assuming this is for square matrix only and does not apply here?

No, you can do elimination on rectangular matrices to get the pivots just as well.

> 3. Given the answer being 1 and considering the above, I try and work backwards, set the following with an example of how I can achieve a single row, is this correct?

- Dimension of nullspace = number of columns without pivots
- Dimension of row/column space = number of pivots

Their sum obviously equals the number of elements in a row. So yes the answer is $5 - 4 = 1$.

Your single non-zero row example is valid but trivial. You can have multiple non-zero rows in $A$ that all become zero rows (and thus produce no pivots) after elimination. This is the case when the rows are *linearly dependent*.

For example, the dimension of the row space of the following matrix is also 1.

$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

> 4. Feels like a roundabout way to address this question. Is there a more efficient way to tackle this question?

Imo the pivot view is one of the most intuitive. Another way is to see from a vector space viewpoint:

- $A$'s columns are vectors of $R^m$, but don't necessarily *spans* all $R^m$. It's like many $R^3$ vectors that all lie on the same plane/line (linearly dependent) cannot produce all vectors of $R^3$.
- $A$'s rows are vectors of $R^n$, but don't necessarily *spans* all $R^n$
- The dimensionality of $A$, i.e., $dim(A)$, is the number of linearly independent $R^m$ vectors among its columns, or linearly independent $R^n$ vectors among its rows. Either ways this number is the same.

The two viewpoints agree nicely, as the number of pivots signal the number of linearly independent vectors among $A$'s rows/cols.

I suggest going through "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang to get a firm hold of the basics. Most of what I write here was taken from his book.

Comment: Thanks @bui! on point (3) trying to understand row/column space better. Does row space and column space mean the same thing since pivots are in both rows and columns? Understand the $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ you gave has “row space dimension” of 1, is it’s “column space dimension” = 3? (Or is the column and row space one and the same here?)

Comment: @nvs0000 Column space is the set of all vectors creatable by linearly combining $A$'s *columns*, and contains vectors in **$R^m$**. Row space is that creatable by linearly combining $A$'s *rows*, and contains vectors in **$R^n$**. They are very different. While a plane on $R^3$ may *look* 2D, its vectors are definitely $R^3$ vectors, not $R^2$ ones. You cannot compare $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ to begin with. The one thing they have in common, though, is the **number** of independent basis vectors, i.e., dimensionality.

Comment: @nvs0000 So yeah, the dimensions of column space and row space are always the same (both are 1 in the example). The column space has one independent $R^2$ basis vector \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\end{bmatrix}, while the row space has one independent $R^3$ basis vector \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.

Comment: Makes so much sense! When I RREF a 7x5 matrix, no matter how I cut it it's always rank/dimension 5. While row space and column space describe different parts of the matrix (I think that's what confused me). **Dimensions** of row space and column space are always the same. Thank you so much.

Comment: @nvs0000 Given that you always get rank/dimension of 5, I assume that you are RREF-ing a random matrix. In general, rank/dimension/num pivots can be any integer between 1 and min($m,n$).

Comment: Oh I thought that applied to all matrix... Do you mean Rank/dimension of a 7x5 matrix can be larger than n (i.e. 7..?) how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135486/discussion-between-bui-and-nvs0000).